# Download a file from web browser to Micro SD card

Tags: stm32, ethernet, sd, server

I am trying to do a web server to store a file (mostly MP3) on a Micro SD card.

I have stm32f407-discovery and w5500 and a Micro SD card reader (unbranded manual pcb drawed).

1. How can I open a web server with w5500?
2. How can I write files on the Micro SD card with the sm32f4?
3. How can I download files from the web browser onto the Micro SD card?

Answer (score 1):

1. The W5500 is an ethernet and TCP/IP controller. [OSI Model layer 4.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)
   Short story, the W5500 is not a web server, and will never be. To get a web server, you have to run one on the STM32F4.
   The advantage is that you don't have to worry about layer 4 and below.
2. You use the SDIO peripheral. This requires a driver. If you want the contents of the SD cards to be readable by a PC you also need software for the filesystem.
3. You have to write your application with web server to support this.
   This is very broad and cannot be answered. Many ways to do this.